# Looping for every character in a string in Python decoder ring

Tags: python, string, decoder, caesar-cipher

I'm trying to make a simple decoder ring in Python.

Example:

```
a=b, `b=c, c=d, etc.
```

I want the script to take an encoded message and output the decoded message.
For instance, I would input `"ifmmp"` and it would output `"hello"`.

I've been thinking I need to split all the characters up and loop through them and change their `chr()` or `ord()` values.

There doesn't seem to be any documentation for this in python.

Comment: What documentation exactly do you think is missing? `for` loops are documented as are `chr()` and `ord()`. Remember that strings are immutable so you cannot just change one string into another, you have to create a new completely string with the new value. Also unless this is homework on how to do a simple for loop you probably want to forget loops entirely and just call `string.translate()`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about:

```
s = 'ifmmp'
new_s = ''
for c in s:
    n = ord(c)
    n = n - 1
    if n < ord('a'):
        # 'a' -> 'z'
        n = ord('z')
    new_s += chr(n)
# print('new_s = %r' % new_s)  -> new_s = 'hello'
```

Of course, this is only handling small letters, not capital.

Comment: Sorry, but this solution has some deficiencies. A minor one is that the function must obtain ord('a') for each character c in s: replacing with number 97 would be better. A bigger one is that ``new_s += chr(n)`` creates a new string for each character of s. If the text is 10000 long, you see the useless work... A major deficiency is that capital letters are treated indeed, as all the characters having an ord() < 97 that is to say digits, capital letters, characters !"#$%'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_` and \t \r \n and others... More in the edit of my answer

Comment: @eyquem [Magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) are never a solution I would recommend.

Answer (score 4):

Forget loops, whenever possible use the features built in to Python:

```
from string import maketrans, translate, ascii_lowercase
import functools
translation = maketrans(ascii_lowercase, ascii_lowercase[-1]+ascii_lowercase[:-1])
decipher = functools.partial(string.translate, table=translation)

print(decipher("ifmmp")) # 'hello'
```

Comment: For the record, `maketrans` is a static function of `bytes` and `bytearrays` in Python 3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031045/how-come-string-maketrans-does-not-work-in-python-3-1

Answer (score 3):

```
from string import maketrans

table = maketrans('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/','zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy ')

for x in ('pdfbo','qipophsbqi','cmvf/nppo/jo/b/sfe/tlz'):
    print x,' -> ',x.translate(table)
```

result

```
pdfbo  ->  ocean
qipophsbqi  ->  phonograph
cmvf/nppo/jo/b/sfe/tlz  ->  blue moon in a red sky
```

.

### Edit

I rewrote the algorithm of Joachim (function **better()**) and I wrote my own solution not using **maketrans()** ( **yop()** ) :

```
s = '{ifmmp}\t\tcmvf-nppo \n SUNNY ~ ajhabh 14568'

def bof(s):
    new_s = ''
    for c in s:
        n = ord(c)
        n = n - 1
        if n < ord('a'):
            # 'a' -> 'z'
            n = ord('z')
        new_s += chr(n)
    return new_s


def better(s):
    li = []
    for c in s:
        n = ord(c)-1
        if n == 96:
            li.append('z')
        elif 96<n<122:
            li.append(chr(n))
        else:
            li.append(c)
    return ''.join(li)

def yop(s):
    gen = ((c,ord(c)-1) for c in s)
    return ''.join('z' if y==96 else chr(y) if 96<y<122 else x for x,y in gen)


def better_yop(s):
    def gen(h):
        for c in h:
            n = ord(c)-1
            if n == 96:
                yield 'z'
            elif 96<n<122:
                yield chr(n)
            else:
                yield c
    return ''.join(gen(s))

for truc in (s,bof(s),better(s),yop(s),better_yop(s)):
    print '%r\n%s\n' % (truc,truc)
```

result

```
'{ifmmp}\t\tcmvf-nppo \n SUNNY ~ ajhabh 14568'
{ifmmp}     cmvf-nppo 
 SUNNY ~ ajhabh 14568

'zhello|zzbluezmoonzzzzzzzzz}zzigzagzzzzzz'
zhello|zzbluezmoonzzzzzzzzz}zzigzagzzzzzz

'{hello}\t\tblue-moon \n SUNNY ~ zigzag 14568'
{hello}     blue-moon 
 SUNNY ~ zigzag 14568

'{hello}\t\tblue-moon \n SUNNY ~ zigzag 14568'
{hello}     blue-moon 
 SUNNY ~ zigzag 14568

'{hello}\t\tblue-moon \n SUNNY ~ zigzag 14568'
{hello}     blue-moon 
 SUNNY ~ zigzag 14568
```

However , my function **yop()** is slower than the function **better()**

.

### Edit

Now the function **better_yop()** has a speed equivalent to the speed of **better()**
However, **better()** seems to be slightly faster than **better_yop()**. Since it is also simpler, **better()** is the best

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend making the decoder ring a dictionary. Then open the input file for reading, read the file, loop through a character at a time and use the dictionary to translate to an output string.  Finally write that string to a file.

Comment: Yes, I ended up using the maketrans solution, but made a translation table for all 26 orders it could be in, then had the program check for outputted english words, and had the english words written to a file.