# how to use string translate in python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am trying to use string translate in Python 3 but it does not seem to work. I looked at other answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031045/how-come-string-maketrans-does-not-work-in-python-3-1)) but up to no avail.

I am using the following code:
Can someone please help me?

```
from string import punctuation
punctuation = dict(list(map(lambda x: [x, None], list(punctuation))))
s = "hello!brother"
s.translate(punctuation)
```